# chef client cancel notifies delayed

Tags: chef-infra

I am wondering if there is a way to cancel a notification to restart a service that was set to delayed.  For example, here is a configuration change code block:

```
template "/etc/myapp/myconfig.conf" do
    source "myconfig.conf.erb"
    mode 0600
    notifies :restart, "service[myapp]", :delayed
end
```

But then at the end of my recipe, I have some logic that will actually disable the app if certain conditions are met.  This works fine, but then just after the disable (at the end of the chef run), the delayed restart request kicks in and restarts the process.  I'm wondering if there is a way to tell chef to cancel all restart requests for the service if it get's disabled.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but it is not pretty.  You would need to reach into the [`run_context`][1] and get a hold of the [`delayed_notification_collection`][2]. You could then remove the notification.  But be aware, this is mucking pretty deeply into the internals of chef, which is highly discouraged.

take a look at [this "cookbook"](https://github.com/tejaycar/chef-hacks) for an example.  It's only been tested to the extent that the test-kitchen tests exercise it.

Comment: Yes, as you say, this might work but I agree would be highly discouraged.  I looked into perhaps using subscribes, but the problem there is that we have many template and cookbook files that could affect a restart, and that kinda seemed like a hack too.  Perhaps this is just turning into a feature request for the opscode folks to check and see if a service was disabled before the end of the recipe before executing a delayed action.

Comment: Mentioned elsewhere, but I don't think this will work for the reasons discussed on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535197/stop-service-in-chef-after-it-has-been-notified-to-restart/27537213?noredirect=1#comment43510889_27537213

Comment: I just added a link to a github repo with code trying this out.  It does, in fact, work.  But it is ugly, and it has to be done during the collection phase (And after the notification is declared).  In other words, it's a bad solution to an ugly problem.