# Stop Service in Chef after it has been notified to restart

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

So we use a service declared in a third party cookbook:

```
service "some-service" do
  action [:enable, :stop]
  supports :restart => true, :status => true, :start => true, :stop => true
end
```

In our main cookbook, we frequently do stuff like this:

```
resource "mah_resurce" do
  stuff
  notifies :restart, "service[some-service]"
end
```

For our unittests of the code that's being deployed by this cookbook, we want to disable this service.

```
service "some-service" do
  action :disable, :stop
end
```

Except this doesn't work.  So I tried this:

```
file "/tmp/why_you_no_worky" do
  action :touch
  notifies :disable, "service[some-service]"
end
```

This feels wrong.  Is there a better way to do this from within the separate unittesting module?

Comment: It does feel wrong. Hopefully Tensabi or Coderanger will chime in here and tell you I'm wrong, but I don't know of any clean way to do this.  Because notifications run AFTER all of your code, you either have to add a final notification, OR manually modify the notification collection.  Both are pretty ugly answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option I can think of off hand would be to temporarily replace the `restart_command` with a no-op.

```
ruby_block 'stop service' do
  block do
    r = resources('service[some-service]')
    r.restart_command('/bin/true')
    r.run_action(:stop)
    r.run_action(:disable)
  end
end
```

Chef would still think it is restarting, but the service would be left stopped. If your service resource doesn't have an explicit restart command, do the same thing for `start_command`.

Comment: Very crafty.  Still cludgy, but better than any ideas I've had.  It does raise a different question I've had for a while; would that change the restart_command for ALL instances of 'service[some-service]'?  or would you have to fine each clone of the resource (Assuming there are clones)

Comment: I just double checked, in Chef 12 there are two parts to the ResourceCollection, ResourceList and ResourceSet. As the names imply, the set _can't_ have duplicates, and `resources` only operates on the set. When you use the same-name-cloning thing it adds a new entry to the list but _overwrites_ in the set, so this will find the last one.

Comment: Cool thanks for looking.  And yikes.  That changes things a bit.

Comment: Is there no way to access the notification queue? The :restart notifications could be removed from there, however i think that the code won't become so much nicer.

Comment: I don't think so, the actual master list of delayed notifications lives in the [`Runner` object](https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/runner.rb#L65) which isn't exposed to the recipe DSL anywhere. The only reference to the active `Runner` object lives in the `Client` instance, but that is also not visible to recipe code. The only way I can see to wipe a queued notification would be via `ObjectSpace` and just ... no.

Comment: What about the delayed notification collection in run_context? https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/run_context.rb#L59  I thought you could remove it from there?  I wouldn't go there, as it is a major hack, but I would expect that to work.

Comment: No, that is used to collect data during the run but as you can see from the https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/runner.rb#L65 it gets copied it to the array in Runner after each resource is converged. Might be a compile vs. converge time split?

Comment: Yep, confirmed.  So long as you remove it at compile time you can rip it out of the run_context.  At that point it's a "possible" notification.  When the notifying resource is actually "updated_by_last_action" the notification gets added to the Runner, and is much harder to remove.  So this could be done in a recipe or library, but not within an LWRP. (unless someone is sneakier than I am)  But it's still a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Another opportunity would be to cancel the existing delayed notification. I think it is a better way, because you don't have to modify your recipes. Unfortunately Chef does not provide such functionality and you have to *"hack"* a bit into Chef inner parts.

Check out this question: [chef client cancel notifies delayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655604/chef-client-cancel-notifies-delayed)

And check out [this cookbook](https://github.com/tejaycar/chef-hacks)

Comment: I don't think that answer is correct, see my comments above about why you can't remove delayed notifications easily.

Comment: From what I can tell, if you remove them during the compile phase, I think you're OK, as they never get added to the runner's delayed_actions.  But if you try to remove them during the execution phase, you're going to be in real hurt.

Comment: I went ahead and coded it up, because it has been bugging me.  It's UGLY, and I wouldn't do it outside of testing, but it does work.  I added a link in this answer with the cookbook code.